# Sampling from a multi-indexed Pandas Series where one index is a datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-indexed (2 indices) Pandas Series that I would like to sample from with a matrix of multi-index references. When they are both non-time variables I know how to make this work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Create a multiindex series
s = pd.Series(np.arange(6), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0, 1], ['a', 'b', 'c']]))
# Make a new series by choosing a bunch of entries 
indexlist = list(zip([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']))
s2 = s_mi.loc[indexlist]
# Results as expected
print(s2)
```

Results:

```
1  a    3
0  b    1
1  b    4
0  c    2
1  c    5
0  c    2
dtype: int32
```

But when one of the indices  is a datetime this doesn't seem to work:

```
# Now do it where one of the indices are time
indexlist2 = list(zip([np.datetime64('1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), np.datetime64('1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), np.datetime64('1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), np.datetime64('1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), np.datetime64('1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), np.datetime64('1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400')], ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']))

s3 = pd.Series(np.arange(6), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[np.datetime64('1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), np.datetime64('1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400')], ['a', 'b', 'c']]))
s4 = s3.loc[indexlist2]
# Results not as expected
print(s4)
```

Results:

```
(1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400, a)   NaN
(1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400, b)   NaN
(1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400, b)   NaN
(1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400, c)   NaN
(1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400, c)   NaN
(1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400, c)   NaN
dtype: float64
```

I assume that at the core of the problem is

```
s.loc[(1, 'a')]
```

works while

```
s3.loc[(np.datetime64('1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'),'a')]
```

returns *IndexingError: Too many indexers*.

What is going on here? How can I get the desired behavior (the values should be [3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 2] as in the non-datetime example)? Is there another way to do this that is better?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `pd.Timestamp` instead as below

```
# Now do it where one of the indices are time
indexlist2 = list(zip([pd.Timestamp('1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'),pd.Timestamp('1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), pd.Timestamp('1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), pd.Timestamp('1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), pd.Timestamp('1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), pd.Timestamp('1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400')], ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']))

s3 = pd.Series(np.arange(6), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[pd.Timestamp('1991-05-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400'), pd.Timestamp('1991-06-14T20:00:00.000000000-0400')], ['a', 'b', 'c']]))
s4 = s3.loc[indexlist2]

# Results should be as expected now!
print(s4)
```

Results :

```
1991-06-14 20:00:00-04:00  a    3
1991-05-14 20:00:00-04:00  b    1
1991-06-14 20:00:00-04:00  b    4
1991-05-14 20:00:00-04:00  c    2
1991-06-14 20:00:00-04:00  c    5
1991-05-14 20:00:00-04:00  c    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: So it is just an issue of which time data types are and are not supported?

Comment: I would say it happens because of the way indices are being handled. Try the following on your old code  `s3.index[0][0]` and `indexlist2[0][0]`. The former will yield  `Timestamp('1991-05-15 00:00:00')` while the later yields `numpy.datetime64('1991-06-15T04:00:00.000000000+0400')`